# Number of real solution of $g(g(g(x))) = \frac{x}{3}$

Tags: calculus

Given $g(x) = 4x(1-x), 0 \leq x \leq 1$ , Then finding  Number of real solution of $$g(g(g(x))) = \frac{x}{3}$$

Attempt: from $g(x) = 4x(1-x),$ then $g(g(x)) = 4f(x)(1-f(x)) = 16x(1-x)(1-4x+4x^2)$

and $g(g(g(x))) = 16f(x)(1-f(x))(1-4f(x)+4(f(x))^2)$

how can i solve 8 degree equation, please help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: There is no closed-form solution for an 8-degree polynomial

Comment: By the way, is $f(x)=g(x)$?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you are not asking to find the values of the solutions, but only how many there are.

A good approach is to show that the graph of $g(g(g(x)))$ has a particular shape.  In particular, that it has three local minima (at $y=0$) and four local maxima (at $y=1$) (in short, that it goes up and down from $y=0$ to $y=1$ a certain number of times between $x=0$ and $x=1$). You will then be able to see the number of times that the line $y=\frac{x}{3}$ intersects the graph.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Your final equation should be coming:
$$x.[3(1-x)^2(8x-1-8x^2)-1]=0\tag{Which ain't 8 degree}$$

Edit: credits to comments

Comment: @dxiv becuase I'm dumb and accidently cancelled $x$ from LHS and RHS. Let me edit

Comment: Don't think the first term is right, compare to [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4z(1-z)+for+z%3D4(4x(1-x))(1-(4x(1-x)))).

Answer (score 0):

$g(g(g(x)))=\dfrac x3$

$⇒(2x-1)^2(2(2x-1)^2-1)=1/(16*4*3)$

Between $0<x<\dfrac{1+\sqrt2}2$, LHD$<0$. 
So $x=0$ is unique solution in given domain.